# HTML Input Type Date - Select and Collapse

Tags: html, datepicker

When using an input type date in HTML5, after the user clicks on a date, the calendar stays expanded forcing them to click away from the calendar to make it collapse. I'd like for this to happen in a single click (i.e. when they click on the calendar, the date is recorded, the calendar collapses and they can get on to other business). Can anyone tell me how to do this? Thanks!

```
<label>Date</label>
<input type="date" id="my_date">
```

Comment: <label for="my_date"></label> or <label>Date<input type="date" id="my_date"></label>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by using a jQuery plugin such as datepicker from jQuery UI:
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [webshims](https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim), which polyfills incapable browsers and gives you nice custom widgets on top of HTML5 form inputs. Here is a [demo, which includes some examples](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/VNuct/) with different configurations.

```
webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
```